# Cannot get UIImage systemName images to change when they are tapped in SWIFT 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS programming but I am using iOS 13 and SWIFT 5 to create a video player. What I am trying to do is play a video once the play.fill button is tapped and then once you the video is playing the image will turn into the pause.fill image. Currently when I run my code everything appears to work in the beginning but when I press the play button it does not change to the pause icon. The image just stays as the play.fill image. I messed with the attribute inspector and was able to fix some other issues I was having with it but now I am stuck. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    var player: AVPlayer!
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var isVideoPlaying = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4")!
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
    }

    @IBAction func playPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if isVideoPlaying{
            player.pause()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            player.play()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .selected)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the image for the `.selected` state:

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .selected)
```

change that to `.normal`:

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
```

---

**Edit**

One assumes you are toggling `isVideoPlaying` somewhere in your code.

Comment: This won't make a difference if OP doesn't toggle `isVideoPlaying` value

Comment: Leo you are correct, but I do have isVideoPlaying = !isVideoPlaying after the if function to create the pause effect. I just tried to cut out as much code as possible to solve this single problem.